# Google Analytics API - access to users' statistics data - adding domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

We want to create a service which, after a client gives us his Google analytics  login and password, will gather some statistical data from his/her analytics account and then will send this data to client's email.

I'm trying to use Google Analytics API.

**Update:**

Thanks to Eike Pierstorff comment, I now know this isn't the way I should follow. So can somebody please tell me what keywords should I search for to get what I want?

Is any of these links related to my question below?:

https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

**Back to original content:**

I'm stuck on "Step 1: Enable the Analytics API" on this page:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php

Precisely, on domain verification on https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification

Well, first of all, this service doesn't even require a domain. WE will be adding clients and their emails and other data to the service's CRM.

But OK, I picked up one of our domains, and I **did** verify it (by putting Google's special html file).

And yes, this domain **is** on the list of verified domains.

Yet, Google console ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php
 ) Before you register you must first verify ownership. You can do this in the Google Search Console. " with a link "Take me there". And it opens https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home

Ok, I think, even if it is verified maybe I'll verify it again, but when try, it says: The domain is already verified.

Please help me...

Comment: At work with little time to help, but at least I can help make you stop barking at the wrong trees: The documentation from the first link is for a service account, it will no help you with your scenario. "Domain Verification" in this case means verifying the Google Apps Domain for the service account (if applicable). Your second link is for domain verification in the Google Search Console, which, despite a similar sounding name, is completely unrelated. A service account is an account created for a program to access GA and must be added to the GA account.

Comment: third your client should not be giving the login and password their google analytics account.   forth you cant use login and password to access the google analytics API.

Comment: @EikePierstorff thanks. Well, this is my first day, actually an hour, with Google API. I simply entered "google analytics api php" in google (I know, we should not type google into google :) and the first link appeared so I tried to follow the steps on this page. Can you then please give me the right link please? I have no idea what to type into google :(

Comment: @DaImTo thank you. These was simply our initial idea, that we will be parsing the GA pages :) we did not even know there is an API for GA.

Comment: @EikePierstorff or maybe give me some hints, what keywords should I search for?

Comment: @EikePierstorff is this the right way to go: https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Or maybe this one: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff - hi again, can you please tell me whether this is even possible. Because when I use the tool located at Add credentials to your project -> Find out what kind of credentials you need, when I choose: Which "API are you using?"= Google analytics, "Where will you be calling the API from?" = Other non - UI, "What data will you be accessing?" = User Data, then it shows a message: "User data cannot be accessed from a platform without a UI because it requires user interaction for sign-in."  - Do I understand correctly, that this is simply impossible?

Comment: Ach, I haven't noticed your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client can authorize your app to retrieve data via oAuth2, but that would require him to be logged in with Google and actively call the application.  If that is okay with you then have a [look at the example here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) (or call out in the comments and I will walk you through the example). OAuth allows to selectively give permission (by setting "scopes") to services, so access could be limited to Google Analytics.

The only other way is to ask clients to add a user (in that case the service account user would do, and you could use  the documentation from the links in your question) on your behalf.

The client cannot possibly give you his credentials, since that would mean you would have access to all his connected services (i.e. you could send Gmail in his name or access his documents on Google Drive).

Comment: I'd like to use your idea from the second paragraph but there is no such thing like "Service Account", when I'm on "Create client ID", under  "Application type" I have the following possibilities:

Web application, Android, Chrome App, iOS, PlayStation 4, Other

Comment: I always forget to call my interlocutors :(

Comment: it finally works! Thank you! Well, at least for my own account. I used your second suggestion along with this: https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP (I could make official Google API client to work).

Comment: * I could NOT make official Google API client to work.